# how to create and initialize an array with another string param

Tags: arrays, shell

```
context 1:

~ arr=( {1..3} 5 {7..10} )
~ echo ${arr[@]}
1 2 3 5 7 8 9 10
```

If I want to store the detail in a string param, like this:

```
context 2:

~ a="{1..3} 5 {7..10}"
~ arr=( "$a" )
~ echo ${arr[@]}
{1..3} 5 {7..10}
```

Is there a simple way which I can use for context 2 to achieve context 1's result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`eval`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#eval), but that [has inherent security risks](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048), so you should first ask if there's a safer way to do this.

Note that I'm assuming `bash` as the shell, because it supports arrays and brace expansion - unlike [the POSIX shell spec.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02)

If you do want to use `eval` after all:

```
a="{1..3} 5 {7..10}"
read -ra arr < <(eval echo "{1..3} 5 {7..10}")
echo "${arr[@]}"
```

The following form works in `bash`, `ksh`, and `zsh`, but it has pitfalls:

```
a="{1..3} 5 {7..10}"
arr=( $(eval echo "{1..3} 5 {7..10}") )
echo "${arr[@]}"
```

The output from the command substitution (`$(...)`) is subject to word-splitting and globbing, which can have unexpected results.
With the input at hand - strings representing integers - this is not a problem, but it's **better not to get in the habit of using `arr=( $(...) )` to fill arrays**.

Unfortunately, though, the `read` syntax differs across shells, so - with extra work and care - it *is* possible to make `arr=( $(...) )` work *robustly* (but if you know that you're only using *one* particular shell, it's usually not worth it):

```
a="{1..3} 5 {7..10}"
# Save the previous $IFS value, set it to the desired separator, and turn off globbing.
oIFS=$IFS; IFS=' '; set -f
arr=( $(eval echo "{1..3} 5 {7..10}") )
# Restore $IFS, turn globbing back on.
IFS=$OFS; set +f
printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}"
```

Comment: Very useful! Thank you!